# Android Animation Sequence Loads Slowly - Appears To Hang

Tags: java, android, animation, android-asynctask, android-animation

I have an animation which displays 5 sequentials dots as my app connects to a web service to parse data. The problem is when a user has a slow cellular connection - the animation takes a few seconds to load. What would be the best method of starting the animation I currently have immediately instead of lagging while it waits to connect?

```
public class UpdateActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private TelephonyManager tm;

    AlertDialog mConfirmAlert = null;
    NetworkTask task;
    ImageView image, text;
    AlertDialog mErrorAlert = null;
    public static ArrayList<String> NameArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> ValueArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> nameArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> ApnArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmscArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmsportArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmsproxyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> portArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> proxyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ImageView mProgressImageview1;
    private ImageView mProgressImageview2;
    private ImageView mProgressImageview3;
    private ImageView mProgressImageview4;
    private ImageView mProgressImageview5;  
    private Button mUpdateButton = null;
    private Button mAssistUpdateButton = null;
    private Button mAssistInstrButton = null;
    private TextView mReadAgainButton = null;
    public static int count;
    public AnimationDrawable mTextAnimation = null;
    private Button assist_update_btn = null;
    TextView mUpdatetext;
    public static InputStream stream = null;
    int version;
    public static BigInteger iD1, iD2, mdN1, mdN2;
    BigInteger[] id, mdnId;
    public static String ICCID, MDN;
    private int mInstructionNumber = 0;
    public static String caR, result;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "DataSettings";

    public static final String Base_URL = "https://apps.example.com/REST/phoneSettings";

    public static XmlParserHandlerFinal handler;
    public static int TotalSteps = 8;

    public FileInputStream fis;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // instance for xml parser class
        handler = new XmlParserHandlerFinal();
        handler.setContext(this.getBaseContext());
        tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        int networkType = tm.getNetworkType();
        int phoneType = tm.getPhoneType();
        version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        // to get MDN(MCC+MNC) of the provider of the SIM and ICCID (Serial
        // number of the SIM)
        // and to check for the Carrier type
        getImpVariablesForQuery();
        task = new NetworkTask();
        if (phoneType == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA
                || (phoneType != TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM
                        && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS
                        && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE
                        && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA
                        && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA
                        && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP
                        && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA
                        && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE)) {
            // If the phone type is CDMA or
            // the phone phone type is not GSM and the network type is none of
            // the network types indicated in the statement
            // Display incompatibility message
            showAlert(getString(R.string.incomp_sm_dialog));
            // Network type is looked because some tablets have no phone type.
            // We rely on network type in such cases
        } else if (!(tm.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT
                || (tm.getSimOperator())
                        .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo)) || (tm
                    .getSimOperator()).equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att)))) {
            // if SIM is present and is NOT a T-Mo or ATT network SIM,
            // display Error message alert indicating to use SM SIM
            showAlert(getString(R.string.insert_sm_dialog));
        }// No SIM or SIM with T-Mo & ATT MNC MCC present
        else if ((tm.getSimOperator()).equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo))
                || (tm.getSimOperator())
                        .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))) {
            // Device has T-Mo or ATT network SIM card MCC and MNC correctly
            // populated
            TotalSteps = 6;
            setContentView(R.layout.updating);

            // AsyncTask to call the web service
            task = new NetworkTask();
            task.execute("");
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == mUpdateButton) {
            // Update button for versions lower than ICS is selected

            onClickMethod(v);

            Intent i = new Intent(this, ConfigFinalActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        } else

        if (v.getId() == R.id.assist_update_btn) {

            // Update button for ICS and up is selected
            // Get the TextView in the Assist Update UI
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
            String text = "";
            CharSequence styledText = text;
            switch (mInstructionNumber) {
            case 0:
                // Retrieve the instruction string resource corresponding the
                // 2nd set of instructions
                text = String.format(getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr),
                        TotalSteps);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                // Update the TextView with the correct set of instructions
                tv.setText(styledText);
                // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                // button is pressed
                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;
            case 1:
                text = getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr2);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                tv.setText(styledText);
                // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                // button is pressed
                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;
            case 2:
                // Final set of instructions-Change to the corresponding layout

                setContentView(R.layout.assist_instructions);
                String assistUpdateInstr = String.format(
                        getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr3), TotalSteps);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(assistUpdateInstr);
                TextView assistInstrText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.updated_text);
                assistInstrText.setText(styledText);
                mAssistInstrButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_instr_btn);
                mReadAgainButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.read_again_btn);
                mAssistInstrButton.setOnClickListener(this);
                mReadAgainButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        } else if (v == mAssistInstrButton) {
            // "LET'S DO THIS" Button in final instructions screen for ICS and
            // up is selected
            // Create ConfigActivity Intent
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ConfigFinalActivity.class);
            // Invoke ConfigActivity Intent to start the assisted update
            startActivity(i);
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS));

        } else if (v == mReadAgainButton) {
            // go back to 1st set of instructions if read again is selected
            mInstructionNumber = 0;
            setContentView(R.layout.assist_update);
            String assistUpdate = getString(R.string.apn_app_text_cta2);
            CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml(assistUpdate);
            TextView assistText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
            assistText.setText(styledText);
            mAssistUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_update_btn);
            mAssistUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    public void onClickMethod(View v) {
        mUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.drawable.btn_update_active_hdpi);

    }

    private void showAlert(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        UpdateActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                });
        mConfirmAlert = builder.create();
        mConfirmAlert.show();
    }


    private void getImpVariablesForQuery() {

        long d = 1234;
        BigInteger divisor = BigInteger.valueOf(d);
        // to get MDN
        //MDN = tm.getLine1Number();
        MDN = "3055861092";
        if (MDN.equals("")) {
            mdN1 = null;
            mdN2 = null;
        } else {

            Log.d("MDN", MDN);
            BigInteger bInt = new BigInteger(MDN);
            mdnId = bInt.divideAndRemainder(divisor);
            // to retrieve ICCID number of the SIM
            mdN1 = mdnId[1];
            System.out.println("MDN%1234 = " + mdN1);
            mdN2 = mdnId[0];
            System.out.println("MDN/1234 = " + mdN2);

        }
        ICCID = tm.getSimSerialNumber();
        if (ICCID.equals("")) {
            iD1 = null;
            iD2 = null;
        } else {
            Log.d("ICCID", ICCID);

            BigInteger bInteger = new BigInteger(ICCID);
            id = bInteger.divideAndRemainder(divisor);
            iD1 = id[1];
            System.out.println("ICCID%1234 = " + iD1);
            iD2 = id[0];
            System.out.println("ICCID/1234 = " + iD2);
        }
        // Check for the Carrier Type
        if ((tm.getSimOperator()).equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo))) {
            caR = "TMO";
        } else if ((tm.getSimOperator())
                .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))) {
            caR = "ATT";
        }

    }

    // method to save the ArrayLists from parser
    public static void setArrayList() {
        nameArr = handler.getnameArr();
        ApnArr = handler.getApnArr();
        mmscArr = handler.getMMSCArr();
        mmsproxyArr = handler.getMmscProxyArr();
        mmsportArr = handler.getMmsPortArr();
        proxyArr = handler.getProxyArr();
        portArr = handler.getPortArr();
        count = handler.getCount();
        result = handler.getResult();

    }



    public ArrayList<String> getnameArr() {

        return nameArr;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getApnArr() {

        return ApnArr;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getMMSCArr() {

        return mmscArr;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getMmscProxyArr() {

        return mmsproxyArr;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getMmsPortArr() {

        return mmsportArr;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getProxyArr() {

        return proxyArr;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getPortArr() {

        return portArr;
    }

    // AsyncTask to call web service
    public class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, InputStream> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //
        }

        @Override
        protected InputStream doInBackground(String... params) {
            int result = 0;

            {
                Log.i("url...", Base_URL);

                try {
                    stream = getQueryResults(Base_URL);
                } catch (SocketTimeoutException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SSLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SAXException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                // The code below plays a ST Promo animation
                // prior to displaying update success or failure message
                for (int incr = 0; incr < 2; incr++) {
                    // Sleep for 1/2 second
                    // Invoke UI to change updating text to show 1 dot
                    // And Increasing the level to reduce the amount of clipping
                    // and
                    // slowly reveals the hand image
                    publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                            R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty,
                            R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    }
                    publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                            R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_empty,
                            R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    }
                    publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                            R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full,
                            R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    }
                    publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                            R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full,
                            R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    }
                    publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                            R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full,
                            R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full);

                    // Sleep for 1/2 second
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    }
                }

                    return stream;
            }


        }
        /*
         * Sends a query to server and gets back the parsed results in a bundle
         * urlQueryString - URL for calling the webservice
         */
        protected synchronized InputStream getQueryResults(String urlQueryString)
                throws IOException, SAXException, SSLException,
                SocketTimeoutException, Exception {
            try {
                // HttpsURLConnection https = null;
                String uri = urlQueryString;

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                BasicNameValuePair mdn1, mdn2,id1,id2;
                if (MDN.equals("")) {
                    mdn1 = new BasicNameValuePair("mdn1", null);
                    mdn2 = new BasicNameValuePair("mdn2", null);
                } else {
                    mdn1 = new BasicNameValuePair("mdn1", mdN1.toString());
                    mdn2 = new BasicNameValuePair("mdn2", mdN2.toString());

                }

                BasicNameValuePair car = new BasicNameValuePair("car", caR);
                if (ICCID.equals("")) {
                     id1 = new BasicNameValuePair("id1", null);
                     id2 = new BasicNameValuePair("id2", null);
                } else {
                     id1 = new BasicNameValuePair("id1",
                            iD1.toString());
                     id2 = new BasicNameValuePair("id2",
                            iD2.toString());
                }

                nameValuePairs.add(mdn1);
                nameValuePairs.add(mdn2);
                nameValuePairs.add(car);
                nameValuePairs.add(id1);
                nameValuePairs.add(id2);

                UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                        nameValuePairs, "ISO-8859-1");
                KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore
                        .getDefaultType());
                trustStore.load(null, null);

                SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
                sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

                HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
                HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

                SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
                registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                        .getSocketFactory(), 80));
                registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

                ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
                        params, registry);

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
                params = httpClient.getParams();
                HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, true);

                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
                httpPost.addHeader("Authorization",
                        getB64Auth("nmundru", "abc123"));

                httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

                Log.v("httpPost", httpPost.toString());

                httpPost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                System.out.println("response...." + httpResponse.toString());
                Log.v("response...", httpResponse.toString());

                stream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

                // save the InputStream in a file

                try {

                    FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("settings.xml",
                            Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

                    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(stream);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(in));
                    String strLine;
                    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                         System.out.println(strLine); //to print the response
                        // in logcat
                        fOut.write(strLine.getBytes());

                    }
                    fOut.close();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                fis = openFileInput("settings.xml");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                tryagain();

            } finally {
                // https.disconnect();
            }

            return stream;
        }

        private String getB64Auth(String login, String pass) {
            String source = login + ":" + pass;
            String ret = "Basic "
                    + Base64.encodeToString(source.getBytes(), Base64.URL_SAFE
                            | Base64.NO_WRAP);
            return ret;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(InputStream stream) {
            super.onPostExecute(stream);
            // This method is called to parse the response and save the
            // ArrayLists
            success();

        }

        public void success() {

            // to parse the response
            try {
                handler.getQueryResponse(fis);
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // set method to save the ArryaLists from the parser
            setArrayList();
            Intent i = new Intent(UpdateActivity.this, ConfigFinalActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();

        }
        // Framework UI thread method corresponding to publishProgress call in
        // worker thread
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            // Call function to update image view
            setProgressImgView(progress[0], progress[1], progress[2],
                    progress[3], progress[4]);
        }

    }

    private void setProgressImgView(Integer imgViewId1, Integer imgViewId2,
            Integer imgViewId3, Integer imgViewId4, Integer imgViewId5) {
        // update image view with the updating dots
        // Reset view layout in case orientation while updating
        setContentView(R.layout.updating);
        mProgressImageview1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty1);
        mProgressImageview2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty2);
        mProgressImageview3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty3);
        mProgressImageview4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty4);
        mProgressImageview5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty5);
        mProgressImageview1.setImageResource(imgViewId1);
        mProgressImageview2.setImageResource(imgViewId2);
        mProgressImageview3.setImageResource(imgViewId3);
        mProgressImageview4.setImageResource(imgViewId4);
        mProgressImageview5.setImageResource(imgViewId5);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();

        if (mErrorAlert != null)
            mErrorAlert.dismiss();
    }

    public void tryagain() {
        // Displaying final layout after failure of pre-ICS automatic settings
        // update
        setContentView(R.layout.tryagain);
        String tryAgainText = "";
        CharSequence styledTryAgainText;

        tryAgainText = String.format(getString(R.string.tryagain_text1),
                TotalSteps);
        styledTryAgainText = Html.fromHtml(tryAgainText);
        TextView tryAgain1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tryagain_text1);
        tryAgain1.setText(styledTryAgainText);

        tryAgainText = String.format(getString(R.string.tryagain_text2),
                TotalSteps);
        styledTryAgainText = Html.fromHtml(tryAgainText);
        TextView tryAgain2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tryagain_text2);
        tryAgain2.setText(styledTryAgainText);

        tryAgainText = String.format(getString(R.string.tryagain_text3),
                TotalSteps);
        styledTryAgainText = Html.fromHtml(tryAgainText);
        TextView tryAgain3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tryagain_text3);
        tryAgain3.setText(styledTryAgainText);

    }
    private void assistUpdate() {
        // Displaying final layout after pre-ICS automatic settings update
        setContentView(R.layout.assist_update);
        assist_update_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_update_btn);
        assist_update_btn.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

    }

    public void success() {

        // to parse the response
        try {
            handler.getQueryResponse(fis);
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // set method to save the ArryaLists from the parser
        setArrayList();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ConfigFinalActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();

    }

    public String getResult() {

        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: I've seen that question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790608/android-java-removing-sequential-loading-animation-delay

Comment: The suggested fix did not work...

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: Asking the same question again is not correct, and is likely to get this question closed. One problem is that the code you've pasted in is huge, and few people have the time to spend working through it. Are you able to narrow the code down to a few core lines, or provide a proof of concept that demonstrates the problem but is significantly shorter? By doing this you may obtain more interest in the question.

Comment: Also, please reduce the code to the _minimum_ required to generate the issue.

Comment: 1) Please do not repost questions. 2) Please do not create additional accounts to repost questions. Both behaviors will simply end up with you not being able to post questions at all.